# Multi-Zone Load Balancing with Elastic Beanstalk and NAT

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have been trying to set up Elastic Beanstalk so that all instances across multiple availability zones appear externally to have the same static IP address.  To do that, I followed the instructions here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/elastic-beanstalk-static-IP-address/

I also followed the prerequisites here:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/nat-gateway-vpc-private-subnet/

I created a demo environment (PHP) and installed the sample application - just for a proof of concept.  Everything works fine as long as I use only a single availability zone (load balancer is in a public subnet and there are two other private subnets for each instance - but all are in the same availability zone).  The moment I try to modify Elastic Beanstalk so that some of the instances are in a different availability zone, I have mixed results.  Sometimes I am able to get the application to load in my browser, and other times it just times out.  I have tried various combinations of enabling / disabling cross zone load balancing, and I get the same results either way.

When I look at the load balancer, all instances show "In Service", and Elastic Beanstalk reports a status of "OK".  When I run the VPC Reachability analyzer, it shows that each instances is reachable from the Internet Gateway.

Here is the configuration I have set up:

### Availability Zone us-east-1c

- Subnet 1 (public): This subnet routes traffic to the Internet Gateway.  This is the subnet where the load balancer resides.
- Subnet 2 (private): This subnet does not route anything to the Internet Gateway.  Instead, it routes all outbound traffic to the NAT (which also resides in the public subnet).
- Subnet 3 (private):  This subnet is identical to Subnet 2 (uses the same routing table).

### Availability Zone us-east-1b

- Subnet 4 (private):  This subnet is identical to Subnet 2 (uses the same routing table).

### Availability Zone us-east-1d

- Subnet 5 (private):  This subnet is identical to Subnet 2.

So what I am seeing is that as long as I deploy instances only to subnets 2 and 3, everything works fine.  As soon as I try to add instances in subnets 4 or 5, that's when the application starts becoming intermittent.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

I should also point out that I am trying to load this application in my browser by referencing the URL of the load balancer, and also the auto-generated Elastic Beanstalk URL for the environment.  The behavior is the same in both cases.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have a couple of questions. Which load balancer is it? Application or Network? I have faced such a problem in the past, but my application load balancer was in the private subnet. I deployed it in a public subnet with the target groups having instances of the private subnet. Once the tg healthchecks passed, my requests started going through. Also, did you check if the requests are coming into the server?

Comment: It is a classic load balancer, and I found the solution.  I created two more public subnets - one in us-east-1b and one in us-east-1d.  Now I have a public subnet in each availability zone.  I deployed the load balancer to all of those public subnets, and then everything started working.  So it seems that in order for the load balancer to communicate with an instance in a private subnet, it needs to be deployed to a public subnet in that same availability zone.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a public subnet in each availability zone and deploying the load balancer to each of those public subnets.  After that, everything worked.